# "Белая известь" и "гашеная известь"— фразеологизмы?

Tags: фразеология

Будут ли являться фразеологизмами словосочетания "белая известь" и "гашеная известь", если основываться на том, что фразеологизмами являются устойчивые сочетания — термины науки?

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Слова "белая" и "гашеная" используются в стандартном значении.

Фразеологизм - это устойчивый оборот речи, свойственный определённому языку и потому дословно не переводимый на другие языки, имеющий самостоятельное значение, которое в целом **не является суммой значений входящих в него слов**.

У фразеологизмов нестандартное, **не дословное** значение. Значение фразеологизмов в какой-то мере переносное.

Comment: Исходя из данного вами определения, является ли фразеологизмом "морская свинка"?

Comment: Это не моё определение, а из словаря Ефремовой. Не думаю, что названия можно считать фразеологизмами.